# Detect barcode scanning event from android-based mobile barcode scanner

Tags: android, barcode

There is a device with embedded laser barcode scanner and hardware SCAN button on Android 4.4.2. Is there any method to hook qr scan event with java interface?
Device is Sunlux xl-8681d but it detects as x301 in adb device list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have worked with similar device. When you click on some area where you can edit text, and scan a bar code, will it print it on the field? If yes, then you can use the following snippet inside your `Activity`:

Override `dispatchKeyEvent` method. Small sample:

```
   @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getCharacters() != null && !event.getCharacters().isEmpty())
        //Add more code...
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);

    }
```

Comment: It works. Thank you. I tried dispatchKeyEvent but without any EditText, with no effect.

Comment: can't get data without edit text

Answer (score 3):

You can do it even without EditText. You need to subscribe for broadcast intent like this:

```
const val QR_ACTION: String = "android.intent.ACTION_DECODE_DATA"
const val QR_EXTRA: String = "barcode_string"

private val receiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            try {
                Timber.d("Get intent ${intent.action}")
                if (QR_ACTION == intent.action) {
                    if (intent.hasExtra(QR_EXTRA)) {
                       val code = intent.getStringExtra(QR_EXTRA)
                       Timber.d("New QR code $code")
                       // now you have qr code here 
                    }
                }                    }
            } catch (t: Throwable) {
                // handle errors
            }
        }
    }
```

Please check QR_ACTION and QR_EXTRA first in to your scanner settings it can be different for different brands.